# How to rerender a component using useEffect with only a State without loop

Tags: reactjs

I have a useEffect that call API when load. I too have a State with data got of API.
When i will make the delete function, it doesn't rerender the component

If i use this state as dependency of useEffect, happen a loop

```
function Employees() {
  const [employeesData, setEmployeesData] = useState([]);

  function removeEmployee(id) {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/api/employees/${id}`)
  }

  function getEmployees() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/employees").then((response) => {
      setEmployeesData(response.data);
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getEmployees();
  }, []);

  return (
      {employeesData.map((element) => {
        return (
          <ContainerTexts key={element.id}>
            <RoundedButton onClick={() => removeEmployee(element.id)}>
              X
            </RoundedButton>
          </ContainerTexts>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Send the list of the employees in the server's response of the delete. and you setEmployeesData in the response of the delete:

```
axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/api/employees/${id}`).then((response) => { setEmployeesData(response.data); }
```

Comment: There is a second way, you can execute `getEmployes()` inside delete function, but answer above would be better approach.

Comment: I have tried this, the problem is infinite loop of requests when i put employeesData as dependency. When is a dependency, work norma usually, but stay in loop of requests

Comment: yes, let your useEffect as shown in your image, no need to add dependency in it or it will go inside everytime your variable is changed.

Answer (score 1):

After performing the delete, re-fetch the updated data:

```
axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/api/employees/${id}`).then(() => {
  getEmployees();
});
```

That operation will update the state, which will re-render the component.

---

Alternatively you could examine the response from the `delete` operation to see if it *already has* the updated data, or information you could use to update your state.  Or you could update your state manually based on the element that was deleted.  For example:

```
axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/api/employees/${id}`).then(() => {
  setEmployeesData([
    ...employeesData.filter(e => e.id !== id)
  ]);
});
```

---

The benefit of the first approach is simplicty, but the drawback is that it makes an additional request to the server.  The benefit of the second approach is performance, but it's slightly more complex and carries a small risk of a problem with the delete operation causing the data to become out of sync.

But either approach requires the same thing... You need to update the state after the operation completes.